# Strange behavior of GETDATE() when used with COALESCE in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, coalesce, getdate

```
DECLARE @i INT

SET @i=14

SELECT COALESCE(@i, GetDate());
```

Above returns

```
1900-01-15 00:00:00.000
```

now if I change i to 11, result will be

```
1900-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

Should not GETDATE() return current datetime?

Comment: I think you might be slightly confused about how COALESCE works. Why would you expect any COALESCE to return the second parameter if the first parameter is not null?

Comment: its more to do with datatype precedence and then converting int to datetime. As first param is not null, it will see what is the precedence or datatypes involved. Then converts the first non null parameter to the that datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql)

`When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence.`

1900-01-01 + 14 is 1900-01-15, your int is converted to datetime since the second argument to the coalesce is datetime

Comment: thanks. Makes sense after I tried  SELECT CAST(@i as DateTime);.